# how to make a swift dictionary that holds two items that are array of other items

Tags: swift

I'd like to create a dictionary that holds two arrays (one key is called "locations" and the other is "items") like this:

```
 var tmpResults = Dictionary("locations",Array)
 tmpResults["items"]=Array
```

or something like this (neither of which seem to work):

```
  var tmpResults = ["locations",:<Location>,"items":<Item>]
  var tmpResults = ["locations":Array(Location),"items":Array(Item)]
```

but I'm really not sure how to do this in Swift. How would I specify the types that the arrays could hold?

Comment: Will each array hold a different datatype?

Comment: @AndyIbanez yes, I've added some more things I've tried but ...

Comment: Could you please add more information about your objects? E.g. Is there a relationship between the `Location` and the `Item` objects? Maybe even 1:1? To me, this looks like an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be `AnyObject`.

```
var tmpResults: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
tmpResults["locations"] = [location1, location2, location3]
tmpResults["items"] = [item1, item2, item3]

// Assuming location1, location2, and location3 are all of the same "Location" type
// And item1, item2, and item3 are all of the same "Item" type
```

By using `AnyObject`, your dictionaries objects could be almost anything. In this example, you have a dictionary that holds and array of `Locations` at one key, and an array of `Items` at another key.

You do lose some of the nice type-checking Swift does though.

**Edit**

In fact, you could declare it like this, so that the compiler at least knows your dictionary holds arrays:

```
var tmpResults: [String: [AnyObject]] = [:]
```

In either case, you use the array you'd probably do something like this:

```
if let items = tmpResults["items"] as? [Item] {
    // Do something with you items here
}
```

Comment: thx - the use of AnyObject seems a bit against the spirit of Swift so not sure if I would do it this way in like a year but I'll do it now! Still a total noob in terms of Swift but liking it more.

Comment: I agree - using `AnyObject` is not the best practice. However, it's basically the only way to do what you want to do _with a dictionary_. Ultimately, the best solution would be to get rid of the Dictionary... as a last though, have you considered a [tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329)? `(locations: [Location], items: [Item])` Or perhaps better, a `struct`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to hold array in dictionary, you can go with the following code:

```
var tempResults : Dictionary<String, Array<String>>
```

This can be reduced to:

```
var tempResults : [String: [String]]
```

Then you can add your Array items to it:

```
var array1 : [String] = [String]()
array1.append("location1")
array1.append("location2")
array1.append("location3")

var array2 : [String] = [String]()
array2.append("item1")
array2.append("item2")
array2.append("item3")
```

And finally, you can add it to your Dictionary

```
tempResults["location"] = array1
tempResults["items"] = array2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: not sure why someone downvoted (I upvoted) - I think this also would work. went with the AnyObject answer since takes into account the different types.

Comment: @timpone Thanks! I better prefer this rather than going with "AnyObject".